# Excel vba looping through columns and hide based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

Between columns F and BM of the sheet, if any value within those columns is equal to "NULL" then don't hide, otherwise hide that column, the column before and column after. The loop should evaluate every other 3rd starting at column G and ending at column BM.

For example, if column G contains the value "NULL" then do nothing and go to column J (three columns forward). If column J now has no cells with value NULL then hide that column, the column before (column I), and the column after (column K).

This is what Im having trouble with. I am able to hide a column based on if the column contains the value NULL or not.

This is the code variations that I have attempted.

```
Sub SuspenseReport()

Dim allColumns As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim col As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set allColumns = Columns("C:E")
allColumns.Hidden = True

Set allColumns = Columns("BN:DY")
allColumns.Hidden = True

Set allColumns = Columns("EB:EU")
allColumns.Hidden = True

Dim rng1 As Range: Set rng1 = Application.Range("G2:BO8") 'maybe limit the range to just one column and range.offet at the end?


For Each col In rng.Columns 
        If cell.Value = "NULL" Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            GoTo ExitIfStat

         Else: cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True


        End If
    Next col
ExitIfStat:
Next x
'below is another variation I attempted but the for loop would iterate on cell not column 
'Dim i As Integer
'i = -1
'For Each col In Range("G1:BO8")
   '     i = i + 1
     '   If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
      '      If col.Value = "NULL" Then
      '          col.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

     '      Else: col.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    'col.Offset(0, -1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                   'col.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

       '    End If



Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Loop every other column, if that column doesn't have a null hide it and the column to the right and the left. Does this mean only odd columns are of interest? In which case do a loop of step 2, test for if null - if found early exit loop of column range, if not found , offset -1 column,resize the range to 3 columns and union into a variable holding each range to hide. Hide the ranges all in one go at the end. Maybe use special cells to exclude e.g. empty cells.

Comment: Thinking about it. Seems like potential for conflict. If I have a NULL in columns 1 and 4 of range. I won't hide 1 and 2. My loop moves onto 3, no null so I hide 2,3 and 4. I have now hidden 4 which has a NULL. I move onto 5. if 5 has a NULL do I unhide 4? Is there a reason you can be certain only every other column will be fit for purpose?

Comment: @QHarr -- good point, I think some sample data would be needed to give a definite answer one way or the other

Comment: And re my first comment, I meant early exit row loop not column. If the logic can be ironed out, this would be much faster if last used row was found in range and used to determine range to read into array, then do the looping on the array, gather the column numbers using logic I described before, if fit for purpose, then target the sheet to hide the appropriate columns.

Comment: other then what correctly caught by QHarr, the code seems broken: no setting of `rng`, usage of some `cell` range while looping thorugh columns with a `col` variable... maybe @FarisShamsi should tell us the "whole truth" about his actual needs and attempts

Comment: Correction: loop through every 3rd column and evaluate if that column has value NULL so start with evaluating column G, if column G contains a value NULL then do nothing. Next, search column J, if column J doesn't have a NULL value then hide column J, column I and column K next iteration to column M etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
Sub HideColumnWithoutNullString()

    Dim range, colCount, rowCount, hasNull, rowsToCheck

    Dim firstColumn, currentColumn, lastColumn

    Set range = Application.range("G:BM")

    firstColumn = range.Columns(0).Column

    lastColumn = range.Columns(range.Columns.Count).Column

    currentColumn = 0

    rowsToCheck = 1


    For colCount = firstColumn To lastColumn Step 1

        hasNull = False

        For rowCount = 1 To range.Rows.Count Step 1

            If Application.Cells(rowCount, colCount).Value = "NULL" Then

                hasNull = True

                Exit For

            End If

            If rowCount >= rowsToCheck Then
                Exit For
            End If

        Next

        If Not hasNull Then
            range.Columns(currentColumn).Hidden = True
        Else
            range.Columns(currentColumn).Hidden = False
        End If

        currentColumn = currentColumn + 1

    Next

End Sub
```

Where rowsToCheck is the number of rows the script has to check for "NULL" on each column, if it only has to check the first row set its value to 1.

Comment: You are looping every column where the OP states, not once but twice, every other column. Looping every other column, to my mind, runs the risk of hiding columns that shouldn't be hidden. Some logic conflict.

Comment: I have tested this and it does works. But you are right I'm passing two times the column check, changing to >= the rowCount vs rowsToCheck solves it.

Answer (score 1):

This one follows the same logic as Octavio's answer, but will check for an empty column or the value of "NULL".

```
    Sub SuspenseReport()
    Dim col As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Rng = Application.Range("G2:BO8") 
    vLr = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    For Each col In Rng.Columns
        vFlag = False
        For vrow = 2 To vLr
            vX = Cells(vrow, col.Column).Value
            If vX = "" Or vX = "NULL" Then
                vFlag = True
            End If
        Next
        If vFlag Then
            col.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else
            col.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next col
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Do you know how I get this to iterate every 3rd column as opposed to every column in that range?

Comment: @FarisShamsi   change this   For Each col In Rng.Columns to a For Loop step 3 from start to end column